# What is the actual replacement for Context#literal in Scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, macros

I can successfully write

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object WhyDeprecated {
  def macroImpl[T : context.WeakTypeTag](context: blackbox.Context):
      context.Expr[String] =
  {
    import context.universe._

    reify {
      context.literal("Hello").splice
    }
  }
}
```

Though, [`Context#literal` is deprecated](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context):

> Deprecated (Since version 2.11.0) Use quasiquotes instead

However, quasiquotes do not provide the same type:

```
context.literal("Hello").splice : context.Expr[String]

q""" "Hello" """ : Universe#Tree
```

Is there a non-deprecated replacement for `Context#literal` which provides an `Expr[T]` rather than a `Tree`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `context.Expr(q""" "Hello" """)` to retrieve an `Expr` from a tree.

Comment: `c.Expr[String](q""""hello, world"""")`. Worth mentioning that macros can also just return the tree?